# Qt undo/redo and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, undo-redo

In my MDI application I use the Qt undo/redo framework and it works very well.

Now I have implemented an operation that requires a lot of time, so I would like to run it in another thread so that the application is not freezed and the user can work on the other MDI windows meanwhile.

So I have to run the operation in a new thread inside the `redo()` method of my `QUndoCommand`. This is a problem, because:

1. If I wait inside the `redo()` method that the thread has finished, the application freezes, so it is useless.
2. If I don't wait that thread has finished, the `redo()` method returns before the operation is completed, and this can cause a lot of problems and errors (e.g. if the user uses the undo/redo mechanism, it is possible that the commands following the thread command are executed before it is completed).

Any idea?

Comment: Probably you need to selectively disable certain UI commands at the time when worker thread is running. BTW, this applies also to regular commands, not only executed by Undo-Redo framework.

Comment: If a command takes long, and if you don't want to disable parts of UI - you could show the user a modal window with "progress". Similar to when this heavy command executes - is progress visible? Is the interface locked?

Comment: @hauron Now I run the operation in the main thread and I show a modal progress dialog. In this way the user have to wait that the operation is completed and he can't work on the other MDI windows

Comment: @AlexF You are right, I have to diable part of the UI while the command is runnig, but I can't control everithing. e.g the `QUndoView` allow the user to redo more commands with a single click, and this can cause order problems

Answer (score 0):

You have much bigger problems than undo/redo. Change the architecture so that system behavior is sane when asynchronous data processing is underway. The data manager object should indicate when it's busy, and the UI should reflect that. Once you get this working properly, undo/redo will magically work as well.

Comment: If it was so "easy", I did't ask! There are some mechanics inside the Qt undo/redo framework that I can't control. e.g in some circumstances the Qt could call the redo() method of more commands in sequence (it expects that when the redo method returns, the operation is finished)

Comment: Again: the mechanics of the Qt and undo/redo don't come into play as long as the rest of your code doesn't behave correctly.